# Laravel: function returns empty page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Relatively new to the Laravel framework, and I can't figure out why the function is returning a blank page.

```
<?php

class MainController extends Controller {

public function setLanguage($language = 'nl', $page = 'index')
{
    switch ($language) {
        case 'nl':
            $this->showNL();
            break;
        case 'fr':
            echo $language . ' ' . $page;
            break;
        case 'de':
            echo $language . ' ' . $page;
            break;
        default:
            echo "nothing here";
    }
}

public function showNL() {
    return "Display some text";
}

}
```

The function showNL() is called but it just returns an empty html document. Also no laravel errors.

Answer (score 3):

You do nothing with the output of showNL()

try doing:

```
return $this->showNL();
```

Also: never echo or print anything in controller methods, always return the output, so you should change all your switch statements.

Answer (score 2):

Shoudn't it be ?

```
   switch ($language) {
        case 'nl':
            echo $this->showNL(); // Added echo
```

Comment: No, you should never print anything in controller methods.